# Can you use delegatecall in the logic contract of a clone?

Tags: openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#potentially-unsafe-operations forbids usage of delegatecall in the logic contract of a proxied contract. Does it apply to minimal clones as well? Am I right to understand that implementation contract in `clone(implementation)` cannot use delegatecall?

Comment: I tried and it worked, why is it phrased like that: `As such, it is not allowed to use either selfdestruct or delegatecall in your contracts.`?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can...you can have fallbacks in fallbacks in fallbacks using delegate calls.  Just be careful though, delegate calls are always dangerous with storage issues, especially if the underlying contract itself can change.